Docker Fails for Azure Web App Service Cotainer APP
We have an azure infra with vnet.
We have a gradel app and a dockerfile that looks like this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN echo "source /opt/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc

COPY logic/ /app/logic
COPY assets/ /app/assets
COPY utils/ /app/utils
COPY python_specs/sss_env.yml /app
COPY app.py /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN source /opt/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    conda activate && \
    conda install conda && \
    pip install cmake && \
    conda env update -f sss_env.yml

EXPOSE 8080
# conda:
CMD ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "sss-env", "python", "-m", "app", "--port", "8081"]

The docker file builts and runs normally on the local instance (compute/machine). The devops pipeline build and push docker image fine, and nother pipeline deploys the web app using the container:

All looks fine until we try to see the log steam of the web app. In there, all seems fine except this line:

2024-11-27T09:10:07.6520207Z ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(125):
conda run python -m app --port 8081 failed. (See above for
error)/home/LogFiles/2024_11_27_lw0sdlwk0006T6_default_scm_docker.log
(https://somename-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_11_27_lw0sdlwk0006T6_default_scm_docker.log)

We have added the WEBSITE_PORT: 8081 to the Environemnt variables in the web app service:

I am unable to get to the reason why this docker command fails, have looked everywhere.
Would be thankful if someone can help!
P.s
The docker is build and pushed to vnet integrated acr using a normal ubuntu-latest agent
The web app is deployed using a self-hosted agent.
The command: RUN conda env list && conda list -n sss-env gives
# conda environments:
#
base                 * /opt/miniconda
abs-env                /opt/miniconda/envs/abs-env

# packages in environment at /opt/miniconda/envs/abs-env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
aiofiles                  23.2.1                   pypi_0    pypi
annotated-types           0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
anyio                     4.6.2.post1              pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                h4bc722e_7    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2024.8.30            hbcca054_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2024.8.30                pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        3.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
contourpy                 1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
et-xmlfile                2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
exceptiongroup            1.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
faiss                     1.7.2           py310hd7ef7d9_4_cpu    conda-forge
faiss-cpu                 1.7.2                h718b53a_4    conda-forge
fastapi                   0.115.5                  pypi_0    pypi
ffmpy                     0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.16.1                   pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.55.0                   pypi_0    pypi
fsspec                    2024.10.0                pypi_0    pypi
gradio                    5.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
gradio-client             1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
h11                       0.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
httpcore                  1.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
httpx                     0.27.2                   pypi_0    pypi
huggingface-hub           0.26.2                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.10                     pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2022.0.1          h06a4308_3633  
jinja2                    3.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
ld_impl_linux-64          2.43                 h712a8e2_2    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           25_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           25_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libfaiss                  1.7.2            h2bc3f7f_0_cpu    pytorch
libfaiss-avx2             1.7.2            h1234567_4_cpu    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc                    14.2.0               h77fa898_1    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 14.2.0               h69a702a_1    conda-forge
libgfortran               14.2.0               h69a702a_1    conda-forge
libgfortran5              14.2.0               hd5240d6_1    conda-forge
libgomp                   14.2.0               h77fa898_1    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           25_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.28          pthreads_h94d23a6_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.47.0               hadc24fc_1    conda-forge
libstdcxx                 14.2.0               hc0a3c3a_1    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              14.2.0               h4852527_1    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libxcrypt                 4.4.36               hd590300_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.3.1                hb9d3cd8_2    conda-forge
markdown-it-py            3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mdurl                     0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2022.1.0           hc2b9512_224  
ncurses                   6.5                  he02047a_1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.26.4          py310hb13e2d6_0    conda-forge
openpyxl                  3.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   3.4.0                hb9d3cd8_0    conda-forge
orjson                    3.10.12                  pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 24.2                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    10.4.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       22.3.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydantic                  2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pydantic-core             2.27.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pydub                     0.25.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.10.15         h4a871b0_2_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.9.0.post0              pypi_0    pypi
python-multipart          0.0.17                   pypi_0    pypi
python_abi                3.10                    5_cp310    conda-forge
pytz                      2024.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.32.3                   pypi_0    pypi
rich                      13.9.4                   pypi_0    pypi
ruff                      0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
semantic-version          2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                75.6.0             pyhff2d567_0    conda-forge
shellingham               1.5.4                    pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sniffio                   1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
starlette                 0.41.3                   pypi_0    pypi
stringcase                1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.13          noxft_h4845f30_101    conda-forge
tomlkit                   0.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.67.1                   pypi_0    pypi
typer                     0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2024.2                   pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   2.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
uvicorn                   0.32.1                   pypi_0    pypi
websockets                12.0                     pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.45.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge

gives this:

Can you provide additional context about why conda run is failing - RUN conda env list && conda list -n sss-env add this in the docker file

Hi @SureshChikkam
I ahve no idea why it is failing, I have been trying to find the reason for lat 20+ hours. The logs are not sync with deployment, like i seel logs mixed with logs for multiple deployments. I will run your command and update the question.

Open the log file mentioned in the error - https://somename-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_11_27_lw0sdlwk0006T6_default_scm_docker.log Key things to check Missing dependencies, Python-specific errors (e.g., ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError), Issues activating the conda environment.

The output from conda env list and conda list -n sss-env indicates that the environment named sss-env does not exist. Instead, you have an environment named abs-env. This mismatch between the expected and actual environment names is likely the cause of the issue.

@SureshChikkam updated with conda env list output
the logFiles shows nothing except:
024-11-27T09:36:41.2287208Z Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024-11-27T09:44:47.9250722Z chmod: changing permissions of '/temp': Operation not ..some confiurations
2024-11-27T09:45:13 Content root path: /opt/Kudu
2024-11-27T09:45:13Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8181
2024-11-27T09:45:13Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024-11-27T10:39:0510.39.05.500669

The environemnt name is acutlaly abs-env, I just wanted to keep it secret. the command in docker file is actually
CMD ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "abs-env", "python", "-m", "app", "--port", "8081"]
so the environemnt exists
@SureshChikkam

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Azure Web Apps expecting the container to listen on the port defined by the WEBSITE_PORT environment variable (set to 8081 in your case). However, the logs indicate the app listens on port 8181.

The logs indicate that the app is listening on 0.0.0.0:8181 instead of 8081. This is likely the root cause of the issue where Azure expects the app to listen on the port defined by WEBSITE_PORT (which is set to 8081).
The App should bind to port 8081, especially when running inside Azure. You are using conda run to start the app, you may need to explicitly pass the correct port to the application with in the Py code, especially if it's using a framework like FastAPI or Flask.
Set the WEBSITE_PORT environment variable correctly in the Azure Web App and exposed it in the Dockerfile.
Check the CMD statement below:
CMD ["bash", "-c", "conda run --no-capture-output -n abs-env python -m app --port $WEBSITE_PORT"]


chmod: changing permissions of '/temp': Operation not ..some confiurations


If the app requires temporary file storage, change any references to /temp to /tmp. This is a common location for temporary files in Linux-based systems.

Updated Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN echo "source /opt/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc

COPY logic/ /app/logic
COPY assets/ /app/assets
COPY utils/ /app/utils
COPY python_specs/sss_env.yml /app
COPY app.py /app

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies and validate environment
RUN source /opt/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    conda install conda && \
    pip install cmake && \
    conda env update -f sss_env.yml && \
    conda env list

EXPOSE 8081

# Ensure the app uses the correct port from the environment variable
CMD ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "abs-env", "python", "-m", "app", "--port", "8081"]

